# Function doesn't save variable

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to add 1 to a number each time a function is called, but for some reason, the total number is always same.

Here is my current code:

```
 <?php
 $total;

 function draw_card() {          
     global $total;               
     $total=$total+1;            
     echo $total;
 }

 draw_card(); 
 draw_card(); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Is the total number always `12`, by any chance?

Comment: You code echoes `1` then `2`

Comment: Your code works [fine](https://3v4l.org/Q0vT0).

Comment: Are you trying to persist the variable on every reload? Then you should read [What is the difference between session variables & Global variables in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43114580/1022914)

Comment: Mikey thanks this helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would not use globals, but if I was forced at gunpoint I would handle state within the function, so outside variables did not pollute the value. I would also make an arbitrary long key name which I would not use anywhere else.

```
<?php
function draw_card($initial = 0) {
    $GLOBALS['draw_card_total'] = (
        isset($GLOBALS['draw_card_total']) ? $GLOBALS['draw_card_total']+1 : $initial
    );
    return $GLOBALS['draw_card_total'];        
}

// optionally set your start value
echo draw_card(1); // 1
echo draw_card();  // 2
```

https://3v4l.org/pinSi

But I would more likely go with a class, which holds state by default, plus its more verbose as to whats happening.

```
<?php
class cards {
    public $total = 0;

    public function __construct($initial = 0)
    {
        $this->total = $initial;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        return ++$this->total;
    }

    public function getTotal()
    {
        return $this->total;
    }
}

$cards = new cards();

echo $cards->draw(); // 1

echo $cards->draw(); // 2

echo $cards->getTotal(); // 2
```

https://3v4l.org/lfbcL

Answer (score 0):

Since it is global already, you can use it outside the function.

```
<?php


    $total;

    function draw_card() {
    global $total;
    $total=$total+1;
    //echo $total;
    }

    draw_card();
    draw_card();
    draw_card();

    echo "Current Count :", $total;

    ?>
```

Result : 
Current Count :3

This will increment the number of times you call the function.
Since you echoed the result/total each time without a delimiter, you might have considered the output to be `12`(Assumption)

Answer (score -1):

Functions have a scope.. you just need to bring $total into the scope of the function... best to not do it globally but as an argument.

```
$total = 0;
function draw_card($total) {
return $total + 1;
}
$total = draw_card($total);
//Expected Output = 1
$total = draw_card($total);
//Expected Output = 2
```

Comment: `global $total;` should take care of that, even if some people consider it a bad practice. Technically he isn't initializing `$total` though.

Comment: In your example, when you call `draw_card($total)`, you are doing `draw_card(0)` both times and the expected output will be `1` for both.